# Is there any syntactic error in the following line in assembly language ? MOV 1002H,AX

Tags: assembly, x86

Is there any syntactic error in the following line in 8086 assembly language ?

```
MOV 1002H,AX
```

Comment: What is a "synthetic error"?

Comment: Did you mean "syntactic error"?

Comment: MOV [1002H],AX is right . you cant move anyth to a value

Comment: if it's not `gas` asm

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: I had the same thought, but then realized it can't be, because GAS doesn't support `1002H` even in `.intel_syntax noprefix` mode, only `0x1002`.  Also, `mov 0x1002, ax` isn't valid, GAS intel syntax requires `mov [0x1002], ax`.  It can't be AT&T syntax because there's no `%` on AX.  `mov 0x1002, %ax` is a load from that absolute address.

Comment: This is likely a MASM (or TASM) syntax question. `MOV 1002h, AX`would try moving the value in register AX to the immediate value 1002h. That makes no sense and would be an error. If one wanted to move the value in AX to memory address 1002h the syntax would be `MOV DS:1002h, AX` or `MOV [DS:1002h],AX` . Should point out that this would also be an error `MOV [1002h],AX` as it is treated the same way as `MOV 1002h,AX`.The `DS:` (or other appropriate segment) is required.

Comment: TASM and MASM also support `MOV DS:[1002h],AX`.Note: EMU8086 supports `MOV DS:[1002h],AX`but not `MOV [DS:1002h],AX`

Comment: I mean to say that is this statement is syntactically right or wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In common Intel notation, the syntax is `MOV destination, source`.

You can't assign to a constant, so the line should be

```
MOV AX,1002H
```

Comment: `assign to a constant` is a bad turn. You're not talking about script language

Comment: Thank you .You answered me what i wanted.